# Equation $\sin(\pi x)=|\sin(\pi ax)|$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

When $a$ is an integer and $x\in[0, 0.5]$,

is there any closed-form solution to the equation

$\sin(\pi x)=|\sin(\pi ax)|$?

I just want to find the largest solution $x\in[0, 0.5]$ (there are more than one solutions if $a>2$.)

When $a=2$, the solution is easily found by using high-school math, but generally....

Thanks in advance.

This picture is when $a=4$ for example.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Absolute values make things more complicated than necessary.

$sin(a)+sin(b)=2sin(\frac{a+b}{2})cos(\frac{a-b}{2}).$

$sin(a)-sin(b)=2sin(\frac{a+b}{2})cos(\frac{a-b}{2}).$

The first equation's solutions contain the solutions to $sin(a)-|sin(b)|$ when $sin(b) \leq 0,$ the second when $sin(b) \geq 0.$